# Partitioning table on YEAR and create view in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-partitioning, materialized-views

I have 2 problems with a partitioned table in mysql.

My table has three columns

1. id_row INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
2. name_element VARCHAR(45) NULL
3. date_element DATETIME NOT NULL

I modify the table to apply partioning by range on YEAR(date_element) as follows

```
ALTER TABLE `orderslist`  
PARTITION BY RANGE(YEAR(date_element)) 
PARTITIONS 5( 
PARTITION part_2013 VALUES LESS THAN (2014),  
PARTITION part_2014 VALUES LESS THAN (2015),  
PARTITION part_2015 VALUES LESS THAN (2016),  
PARTITION part_2016 VALUES LESS THAN (2017),  
PARTITION part_2017 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));
```

but when I use

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM ordersList WHERE YEAR(date_element) > '2015';
```

the query uses all the partitions and not only part_2015, part_2016 and part_2017.

Instead if I use

```
  EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM ordersList WHERE date_element > '2015-10-10 10:00:00';
```

it works.

So my questions are:

1. How can I make the first query work?
2. Is there a way to create a materialized view from this table without losing the partitions?

Thank you

Comment: I suspect MySQL just isn't smart enough to realize that the function call in the first `WHERE` clause matches the partitioning criteria. It's the same reason that type of query can't use an index on the column.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example: `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM ordersList WHERE YEAR(date_element) > '2015';` there's no way for the engine to identify beforehand in which partition your data is.

It must evaluate `YEAR(date_element)` in every row to find out the year. It's a classic example of filtering by a function's result. DBMS in general can't use indexes to find data this way, since the function's result is unknown and must be evaluated for every table, so your search turns into a full scan.

I understand your point here, since you used the same function the define partitioning and to find data, but for some reason this optimization is not there. In other words: the engine doesn't notice both functions are the same.

In the second statement, you're directly comparing a column to an arbitrary value, this is what the engine prefers, and indexes come into play.

Answer (score -5):

MySQL's `PARTITIONing` is quite finicky.  Whereas `YEAR()` is recognized, it is probably the only expression that is recognized, not `>` it plays dumb.

Why are you partitioning on `YEAR`?  it may not be useful.

If your queries are like what you described. then an appropriate index on a non-partitioned table is likely to run just as fast.

Please provide the important queries and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (with or without partitioning) so we can analyze what makes the most sense.

Also, what is `PARTITIONS 5`??

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: My first paragraph says that `YEAR` does not work with partitioning.  Para #2, 3, 4 try to address the unwritten question of "how do I make this work" with that answer of "not with YEAR or PARTITIONing".

Comment: If the amount of data being queried is significant, an INDEX would be ignored, and a full table scan would occur.

Partitioning is useful in those situations where MySQL refuses to use an INDEX, because an Index would not help.

Comment: @Kennysmoothx - But `YEAR(date_element)` is not sargable, so I don't think it would do partition pruning.